# redirecionamento de URL e PORTA no .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache

Seguinte,
Eu tenho uma URL: http://ip_do_servidor/fop2
O que eu queria fazer é, quando alguem entrar com essa url, o apache redirecionar para o seguinte endereço: http://ip_do_servidor:81/mesa_atendimento/login
Eu já tentei varias coisas inclusive olhei em outras questões daqui da comunidade, porém sempre esbarro no fato da porta ser diferente...
Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso usando o htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Se a porta é 80
#E a URL é /fop2 ou /fop2/
#redirecionar para a nova URL
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule  ^fop2/?$       http://ip_do_servidor:81/mesa_atendimento/login    [NC,QSA,R,L]

#                                 Flags    [NC]  :: ignorar caixa alta/baixa
#                                          [QSA] :: adicionar parâmetros se há na consulta
#                                          [R]   :: redirecionar (não reescrever)
#                                          [L]   :: parar o processamento de outras regras
```

Comment: Cara não funcionou. Sua logica aparentemente está certa, mas vale lembrar que nos navegadores a porta padrão é a 80, então elas não ficam na url. não pode ser por isso?

Comment: A porta não precisa estar na URL. `%{SERVER_PORT}` é uma variável de servidor com a porta correta. Tenho certeza de que isso funciona. Carreguei para um hospedagem grátis em http://mariano.uphero.com/260627/fop2 se quiser testar. Você tem outras linhas no seu .htaccess?

Comment: Seguinte, sua logica tá certa sim, li um pouco sobre o funcionamento do .htaccess e realmente oq vc fez deveria funcionar. Só que meu apache trabalha com diferentes portas/aplicações, acaba que tem mta configuração nele, provavelmente eu que não estou conseguindo usar o .htaccess por falta de colocar alguma conf a mais na parte dos sites-enabled, etc.